# ViewPagerIndicator does not allow setBackgroundResource on ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, drawable, parallax, viewpagerindicator

I'm trying to use a ParallaxViewPager (https://github.com/andraskindler/parallaxviewpager) along with a ViewPagerIndicator (https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator). The problem I'm facing is that I set a Background resource for the ViewPager and it works properly if I do not set a page indicator. But I need the viewpager indicator to work with the ParallaxViewPager.

The code I'm using is

```
    final ParallaxViewPager parallaxViewPager = (ParallaxViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.authentication_opening_fragment_viewpager);
    PageIndicator pageIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) rootView.findViewById(R.id.authentication_opening_fragment_indicator);

    parallaxViewPager.setAdapter(new AuthenticationOpeningPageAdapter(context.getFragmentManager()));
    parallaxViewPager.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_opening);

    pageIndicator.setViewPager(parallaxViewPager);
```

If I don't use the last line, the parallax background image works properly but then I won't have an indicator. If I use the .setViewPager() then my viewpager will have just a blank background.

When debugging it, I found that what "invalidates" the setBackgroundResource is this line on the ViewPagerIndicator library (on CirclePageIndicator file):

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
```

Is there any workaround or something I can do to fix this problem?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Did you figure out how to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

For this to work, you need to modify a little on `ParallaxViewPager` like this

```
private void init() {
    source = new Rect();
    destination = new Rect();
    scaleType = FIT_HEIGHT;
    overlap = OVERLAP_HALF;
    listener = new PageChangeParallaxListener();
    setOnPageChangeListener(listener);
}

public PageChangeParallaxListener listener;

public ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener getPageChangeListener() {
    return listener;
}

public class PageChangeParallaxListener implements
        ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
            int positionOffsetPixels) {
        if (bitmap != null) {
            source.left = (int) Math
                    .floor((position + positionOffset - CORRECTION_PERCENTAGE)
                            * chunkWidth);
            source.right = (int) Math
                    .ceil((position + positionOffset + CORRECTION_PERCENTAGE)
                            * chunkWidth + projectedWidth);
            destination.left = (int) Math
                    .floor((position + positionOffset - CORRECTION_PERCENTAGE)
                            * getWidth());
            destination.right = (int) Math.ceil((position + positionOffset
                    + 1 + CORRECTION_PERCENTAGE)
                    * getWidth());
            invalidate();
        }

        if (secondOnPageChangeListener != null) {
            secondOnPageChangeListener.onPageScrolled(position,
                    positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if (secondOnPageChangeListener != null) {
            secondOnPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        if (secondOnPageChangeListener != null) {
            secondOnPageChangeListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
        }
    }

}
```

And while implementing `CirclePageIndicator`, you have to do this

```
ParallaxViewPager viewPager;
CirclePageIndicator circlePageIndicator;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(your layout);
    //do you view initialization by ID 
    viewPager.setAdapter(your adapter);
    circlePageIndicator.setOnPageChangeListener(viewPager
            .getPageChangeListener());
    circlePageIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
    viewPager.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.parallax_bg);
}
```

Comment: As of the version 0.3.1 of the parallax library, some of the variables are marked as ```private``` and therefore can't extend from ```ParallaxViewPager``` anymore =/